# How to translate code with byte operation from Java to Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, translate

I would like to translate this method in Kotlin but I do not know what are the variables to cast to do things correctly and have the right operations memories :

```
public static UUID bytestoUUID(byte[] buf, int offset) {
    long lsb = 0;
    for (int i = 15; i >= 8; i--) {
        lsb = (lsb << 8) | (buf[i + offset] & 0xff);
    }

    long msb = 0;
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        msb = (msb << 8) | (buf[i + offset] & 0xff);
    }

    return new UUID(msb, lsb);
}
```

Do you have the right way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the good cast to do for the unit tests to work.

```
fun bytestoUUID(buf: ByteArray, offset: Int): UUID {
    var lsb: Long = 0
    for (i in 15 downTo 8) {
        lsb = lsb shl 8 or (buf[i + offset].toLong() and 0xff)
    }

    var msb: Long = 0
    for (i in 7 downTo 0) {
        msb = msb shl 8 or (buf[i + offset].toLong() and 0xff)
    }

    return UUID(msb, lsb)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.experimental.and

 fun bytestoUUID(buf: ByteArray, offset: Int): UUID {
    var lsb: Long = 0
    for (i in 15 downTo 8) {
        lsb = lsb shl 8 or ((buf[i + offset] and 0xff.toByte()).toLong())
    }
    var msb: Long = 0
    for (i in 7 downTo 0) {
        msb = msb shl 8 or ((buf[i + offset] and 0xff.toByte()).toLong())
    }
    return UUID(msb, lsb)
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I thought but I do not know if cast have an impact on performance or memory allocated. As I process a lot of data I will not like the method to be slower. In my mind the cast in java is implicit but in fact I do not know how the bytecode behaves.

Comment: Unit tests did not succeed with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun bytestoUUID(buf: ByteArray, offset: Int): UUID? {
    var lsb: Long = 0
    for (i in 15 downTo 8) {
        lsb = lsb shl 8 or (buf[i + offset] and 0xff)
    }
    var msb: Long = 0
    for (i in 7 downTo 0) {
        msb = msb shl 8 or (buf[i + offset] and 0xff)
    }
    return UUID(msb, lsb)
}
```